# Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile builds are only supported for physical devices. attemped to build for simulator

Tags: flutter, io

Al momento de ejecutar la app en xcode lanza el siguiente error:

Mi version de flutter: 3.7.12

ERROR: Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile builds are only supported for physical devices. attemped to build for simulator

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los mensajes de error y código van como texto, las imágenes solo para mostrar imágenes (o tal vez resultados).